# Javascript issue with http://mysite.com vs http://www.mysite.com

Tags: javascript, http, dns

I've never experienced this problem before, and it just came to our attention because a client was trying to access our page and couldn't see much of the javascript.  He was navigating to http://www.mysite.com, when we've always just gone to http://mysite.com.

There appear to be no problems server-side, as in both url's are pointing to the same place.  There are also no errors on the page when it loads.

Has anyone had to deal with this before?

Comment: If `mysite.com` isn't the actual name of your domain, then I encourage you to use `example.com` in your question instead. `example.com` is one of several domain names that "are reserved for use in documentation and are not available for registration"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your absolute urls reference `http://mysite.com/js/file.js` and there's no redirect in place then the JS files wouldn't get picked up properly, obviously.

Are you aware of Firebug and it's net tab? You can inspect and see if the js files are being retrieved.

It would help if you provided the real link.

Comment: I've used Firebug before, but never the net tab.  I'll check it out.

I would provide the real link, except its a product somewhat still in development for a customer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending the JavaScript only to authenticated users?

If that's the case, then a user that authenticated on http://example.com, will not be able to access pages on http://www.example.com assuming you didn't make any other changes. This is because the cookies set on either (www. or roo) will not be sent to the server when the user navigates to the other.

Comment: No, this is a public site with no authentication.  I'm thinking it has something to do with the path of some .js file I'm trying to load...

Comment: what is your web server setup like and can you give us the actual url to view if its a public site?

Comment: OK, I solved it.  Like a previous poster said, I had an absolute pathname to a .js file hidden in one of my functions that was not resolving when loaded from www

The url is http://shepherdis.com/iupui

Comment: that makes sense, and glad you found it. Absolute pathnames are evil :)